# Shell: Clone sd automatically | Raspbian |

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian, cloning

I need a script that clones the OS from an USB Stick (/dev/sda) to a SD Card /dev/sdb.
But I need to auto detect when a SD card is inserted, so the script starts whenever I plug in a card.

Is there a possibility to register the plugin of a new SD Card so the cloning starts?

Comment: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Please show your coding efforts.

Comment: Did you try asking on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: This is a [job for udev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489306/execute-script-on-insertion-of-sdcard)